# R remove multiple text strings in data frame

Tags: r, keyword, gsub

New to R. I am looking to remove certain words from a data frame. Since there are multiple words, I would like to define this list of words as a string, and use gsub to remove. Then convert back to a dataframe and maintain same structure.

```
wordstoremove <- c("ai", "computing", "ulitzer", "ibm", "privacy", "cognitive")

a
id                text time      username          
 1     "ai and x"        10     "me"          
 2     "and computing"   5      "you"         
 3     "nothing"         15     "everyone"     
 4     "ibm privacy"     0      "know"
```

I was thinking something like:

```
a2 <- apply(a, 1, gsub(wordstoremove, "", a)
```

but clearly this doesnt work, before converting back to a data frame.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
wordstoremove <- c("ai", "computing", "ulitzer", "ibm", "privacy", "cognitive")

(dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 'id text time username
1 "ai and x" 10 "me"
2 "and computing" 5 "you"
3 "nothing" 15 "everyone"
4 "ibm privacy" 0 "know"'))

#   id          text time username
# 1  1      ai and x   10       me
# 2  2 and computing    5      you
# 3  3       nothing   15 everyone
# 4  4   ibm privacy    0     know

(dat1 <- as.data.frame(sapply(dat, function(x) 
  gsub(paste(wordstoremove, collapse = '|'), '', x))))

#   id    text time username
# 1  1   and x   10       me
# 2  2    and     5      you
# 3  3 nothing   15 everyone
# 4  4            0     know
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option using `dplyr::mutate()` and `stringr::str_remove_all()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dat <- dat %>%   
  mutate(text = str_remove_all(text, regex(str_c("\\b",wordstoremove, "\\b", collapse = '|'), ignore_case = T)))
```

Because lowercase 'ai' could easily be a part of a longer word, the words to remove are bound with `\\b` so that they are not removed from the beginning, middle, or end or other words.

The search pattern is also wrapped with `regex(pattern, ignore_case = T)` in case some words are capitalized in the text string.

`str_replace_all()` could be used if you wanted to replace the words with something other than just removing them. `str_remove_all()` is just an alias for `str_replace_all(string, pattern, '')`.

rawr's anwswer could be updated to:

```
dat1 <- as.data.frame(sapply(dat, function(x) 
  gsub(paste0('\\b', wordstoremove, '\\b', collapse = '|'), '', x, ignore.case = T)))
```