# R remove multiple text strings in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, gsub

I have a `vector` of words to remove from a `data.table` `DT` as follows.

```
wordstoremove <- c("Simpson", "Flander", "Nahasapeemapetilon", "Spuckler", "Wiggum")

DT <- structure(list(vid = c("Simpsons", "Flanders", "Nahasapeemapetilons", 
                             "Spucklers", "Wiggums"), wr1 = c("Homer Simpson", "Ned Flanders", 
                                                              "Apu Nahasapeemapetilon", "Cletus Spuckler", "Chief Wiggum"), 
                     wr2 = c("Bart Simpson", "Rod Flanders", "Manjula Nahasapeemapetilon", 
                             "Brandine Spuckler", "Ralph Wiggum"), wr3 = c("Marge Simpson", 
                                                                           "Todd Flanders", "Sanjay Nahasapeemapetilon", NA, "Sarah Wiggum"
                             )), .Names = c("vid", "wr1", "wr2", "wr3"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                       -5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

DT
                   vid                    wr2                        wr2                       wr3
1:            Simpsons          Homer Simpson               Bart Simpson             Marge Simpson
2:            Flanders           Ned Flanders               Rod Flanders             Todd Flanders
3: Nahasapeemapetilons Apu Nahasapeemapetilon Manjula Nahasapeemapetilon Sanjay Nahasapeemapetilon
4:           Spucklers        Cletus Spuckler          Brandine Spuckler                        NA
5:             Wiggums           Chief Wiggum               Ralph Wiggum              Sarah Wiggum
```

I know I can use the solution in [R remove multiple text strings in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645390/r-remove-multiple-text-strings-in-data-frame).

How to do this using `data.table` to minimise copying of data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(data.table)
foo <- function(x) gsub(paste0(wordstoremove, collapse="s?|"), "", x)
DT[, names(DT)[-1] := lapply(.SD, foo), .SDcols = names(DT)[-1]]
DT
#                    vid     wr1       wr2     wr3
# 1:            Simpsons  Homer      Bart   Marge 
# 2:            Flanders    Ned       Rod    Todd 
# 3: Nahasapeemapetilons    Apu   Manjula  Sanjay 
# 4:           Spucklers Cletus  Brandine       NA
# 5:             Wiggums  Chief     Ralph   Sarah
```

Comment: usually just `names(DT)` instead of `colnames(DT)` is used

Comment: and maybe use `s?` to allow for the possibility of plurals

Comment: Yes, I missed it after Crop's edit. What do you mean by `s`?

Comment: I'd think a for-loop with `set()` would be even more efficient (would be nice to check on meaningful data sizes, e.g., 2GB data).

Comment: @Arun, I cant't find out the way to do it fast, but seems that it is. See update

Comment: `?` will match the previous character 0 or 1 times

Comment: @MichaelChirico, you mean `wordstoremove <- c("Simpsons?", "Flanders?", ...)` ?

Comment: nono, I mean to add that to the regex so it matches "Simpson" AND "Simpsons"

Comment: @MichaelChirico, yeah, you're right. `paste` will do it for me. See update